# jQuery .each with progress bar

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar

I am iterating through a table with roughly 250 rows. Each row that does not meet a specific criteria is being removed from footable (which I am running). The `footable.removeRow()` function is very slow and I can not just `.hide()` because of pagination problems.

I want to show a progress bar when this iteration happens (decided by user). I have the following html pulled form bootstrap.

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following javascript code that is executed when the iteration starts.

```
$('.group-show-only').click(function(){
    //parent container
    var pill = $(this).closest('.group-pill');
    //show progress bar
    pill.find('.progress').show();
    //used to determine if row is removed
    var id = pill.attr('group-id');
    //get all table rows
    var rows = $('.footable tbody').find('tr');
    var count = rows.length;
    var i = 0;
    //the actual progress bar
    var bar = pill.find('.progress-bar');
    //the footable
    var footable = $('table').data('footable');
    rows.each(function(){
        //this is the problem, the loop bottle necks, the bar just sits at zero for about 5 seconds, and then jumps to 100
        bar.css('width', (i*100/count) + '%');
        //confirming the bottle neck
        console.log(i);
        if(!$(this).find("input[group="+id+"]").attr('checked')){
            footable.removeRow(tr);
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

The problem is the bar sits at zero for about 5 seconds and then jumps to 100. Resources must be bottle-necking. Is there a way to prevent this so the progress bar smoothing increases and shows the actual progress of the loop?

Thanks

Comment: I think `(i*100/count)` should be `((i/count)*100)`

Comment: That's usually what happens when you update a style in a blocking block of code in a single threaded language, the code finishes, then updates the style. Try adding a timeOut to defer.

Comment: 2*5/10 = 1, (2/10)*5 = 1    :)

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: that shouldn't be a problem, see [this](http://www.bootply.com/nGn81TSHiw). If you add the brackets, it runs the same as without the brackets.   

  RyanY: If you remove the bar.css() function, do the logs came with the same time between them? Isn't it possible, that your table has a lot of row to delete in the first rows (that takes much time), and zero rows to delete at the end?

Comment: try this approach: bar.animate({ width: "+=" + (i*100/count) + '%'}, 5000);

Comment: yes, if you remove the bar.css function the delay is still there. animate did not help either. thanks though.

Comment: I did impoved the animate approach http://www.bootply.com/h2CWsCUReu